# How to property remove objects (immediately)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm finding out that `delete()` of a related object does not delete it immediately. In my case the `Vader` instance comes through `instance` parameter of a serializer's `update` method.

How do I delete `v.son` immediately?

```
class Vader(models.Model):
    pass

class Luke(models.Model):
    dad = models.OneToOneField(Vader, related_name='son')

>>> v = Vader()
>>> hasattr(v, 'son')
False
>>> l = Luke(dad=v)
>>> l.save()
>>> hasattr(v, 'son')
True
>>> v.son
<Luke: Luke object>
>>> v.son.delete()
>>> hasattr(v, 'son')
True
>>> v.son
<Luke: Luke object>
```

Answer (score 3):

The deletion in the database is performed immediately, but it is not reflected in the model instances already loaded. This is not normally a problem since django works like HTTP - request comes in, some processing happens, then the state is lost.

You can force the model to reload from the database to see the changes:

```
v.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: This didn't work. I had to do `v = Vader.objects.get(id=v.id)`. I wonder if this has something todo with the `OneToOne` relationship? A `refresh_from_db()` just queried the `Vader` table, while the `.get()` also queried all `OneToOne` related tables.

Comment: Just to add, after the `.delete()` the `v.son` continues to be a `Luke` object, only its `id` is None. This stayed this way even after `.refresh_from_db()`

Comment: I ended up expanding my check to `hasattr(v, 'son') and v.son.id`. There no database queries with this.